# Relation between modulus of a function at a point and the $L^2$ norm of the function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a very basic question. I have a real valued function $x$ defined on the interval $[0,1]$ and set of points, say, $t_k = \frac{k-1/2}{4}, k=1,\ldots,4$. Can I say that $|x(t_k)| \le \|x\|_{L^2}$ for each $k=1,\ldots,4 ?$ Since $|x(t)| \le \|x\|_{L^2} \forall t\in [0,1]$, won't it be true for these points $t_k$ as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $x(t) = \sin 4\pi t$. We have $|x(t_k)| = 1$ at $t_k = \frac{k - 1/2}{4}$ for $k = 1, \dots, 4$. But $\| x\|_{L^2} = \sqrt{\int_0^1 |\sin 4\pi t|^2 \ dt} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$. This example shows that it is possible to construct a *continuous* function $x : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ such that $|x(t_k)| \leq \| x \|_{L^2}$ fails to hold for $k = 1, \dots, 4$.

What if, instead of insisting that $x$ is continuous, we merely assume that $x$ is an element of $L^2 ([0, 1])$? In this case, the question is meaningless, since an element of $L^2([0, 1])$ is merely an *equivalence class* of functions that are equal almost everywhere. Therefore, we can't evaluate an element of $L^2([0, 1])$ at a specific point. For example, $x_1(t) = 0$ and $x_2(t) = \mathbf 1_{\{1/2\}}$ represent the same element of $L^2 ([0, 1])$ (an element whose $L^2$-norm is zero), and yet $x_1(\tfrac 1 2) = 0$ whereas $x_2(\tfrac 1 2) = 1$.

Finally, let's return to the case of *continuous* functions $x: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$. As we've seen, the inequality $|x(t)| \leq \| x \|_{L^2}$ does not hold for $t \in [0, 1]$. The only inequality of this kind that is valid is the inequality $|x(t)| \leq \| x \|_{L^\infty}$. By definition, $\| x \|_{L^\infty} = \sup_{t \in [0, 1]} |x(t)|$, from which the inequality follows. I'm afraid this is as much as we can say.

Comment: Thank you, you explained it well.